# How do i copy job title(person or group) and paste it into another column as single line of text?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

I have a contacts list workflow which populates an employee's job title and email address when their full name is entered. If i display 'Job Title' (person or group column type) it will show the employee's correct job title.

However, i have excluded this and created a separate column 'Title'(single line of text) because i have external vendors not in the AD and i am using workflows to set the column 'Title' so that it will populate depending on if i key in vendor or employee details.

The problem is that when i use designer workflow to Set 'Title' to Current Item:Job Title , there is no return field as job title, only email,display and the others which are the same.[image]

As String, Login Name and User Id Number just shows my user log in credentials.

The only way this would work is i use 'Person or Group' column type with field as 'job title' then returning field as login name would display the employee's job title. However, i am trying to achieve this using 'single line of text' as i am creating a contacts list with both employees and external vendors details.

[image]

This is my current workflow so that i can populate both external vendor not in AD and employees.

Comment: I think the problem is simply that the job title is not completed in your Active Directory. This would require a feed from your Human Resources department. As String will return the data you require if it contains any information.

Comment: @unibod50 Job title is completed in my company's AD correctly, when returning it as string to a 'person and group' column it will show up correctly as 'Intern', 'Executive Senior IT' etc. I am just trying to return it as string/display to 'Single line of text' column and make it show up correctly rather than  i:0#.w|companyserver\myusername

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is "Job Title" a user profile's property?

Then use "Users profiles" as "Data source" (join by login name) in your "Set 'Title' to Current Item:Job Title" workflow action.